# How do I handle .gitignore in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

To start, excuse my noob-ness as I'm pretty new.

I want to be able to work on an Android project between my desktop and laptop computers, but I'm having an issue with figuring out how to push and pull the files between computers.

I suppose one of my largest issues is I really don't understand gradle. But it seems to always be very important, and extremely fragile, cause it breaks everything any time I update something, or to import a project.

I set up my project with VCS, and it seemed to auto-generate a .gitignore with the necessary things, but when I pushed it to github through Android Studio it seemed to just push everything in the gitignore anyway.

I thought maybe this wouldn't matter, and tried to import the project onto my other machine, but it blew up anyway and told me it was missing modules or something. I'd try to fix this manually but I'd rather figure out how to just make the gitignore work properly. Should I not use the Android Studio VCS and just manually push and pull through bash, or is there something I'm missing?

I can't figure out if my issue is with the export of it to git/Github, or with the pull on my new machine, not having something configured properly.

If it helps, my project is at:
https://github.com/Ashanmaril/Quotr

If someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I don't see anything in your repo that shouldn't according to the `.gitignore`. What is the "everything" that seemed to be pushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean that you pushed .idea folder to github, you should edit .gitignore to have line `/.idea/` or just `.idea/`, you will have to remove .idea folder manually by:

```
git rm --cached -r .idea
git commit -am 'Removed .idea folder'
git push origin master
```

The folder with idea config will not be deleted from your disk, only from repo.

Comment: Ah, it seems that I was wrong about the stuff in the gitignore being pushed. I was confused because of how many gradle files there are.

So that leads me to the question, should I have all those gradle files in there? It broke when I tried to import it into Android Studio on my other machine. Unless that's just cause the .idea was in there.

Comment: You should not commit .idea, .gradle, .git/ files because they contain system-dependent configuration and you will get a lot of problems when trying to run same project on different computer. Those files are auto-generated anyway.